# How to find iso file in macOS Big Sur downloaded file?

Tags: windows-10, mac, vmware, iso-image

I want to run macOS Big Sur using VM Ware. I Downloaded the macOS Big Sur file but I can’t find the ISO file. I extracted the files, but I cannot find it. All folders I see are:

```
.fseventsd
.HFS+ Private Directory Data_
[HFS + Private Data]
BaseSystem
Firmware
Install macOS Big Sur.app
Library
System
usr
```

And some files.

How do I find the ISO file?

Comment: Check inside the `Install macOS Big Sur.app` file.

Comment: There is no ISO file. But you can create one, the internet will point your way.

Comment: macOS doesn't really use .iso files. It prefers a more sophisticated disk image file format called a .dmg. It's probably inside the "Install macOS Big Sur.app" bundle/package (a .app is a  directory). Wherever it is, it's the only thing that's several gigabytes in size, so you could even hunt it down by repeatedly descending into the largest directory until you find it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score -2):

VMware is said to be incompatible with macOS on Windows 10.

To patch VMware, you need to install
[Auto-Unlocker](https://github.com/paolo-projects/auto-unlocker),
then run `Unlocker.exe`. Download also the
[macOS ISO](https://partages.wiki-tech.io/files/ISO/APPLE/MACOS/ISO-VM/).

You then create the VM for macOS. Give it at least 4 GB of RAM and
2 processors, and define the downloaded macOS as the DVD.

In the VM Settings, Hardware tab, USB Controller line, set
USB compatibility to USB 3.0.

You need now to edit the VM's configuration `.vmx` file, as follows.

For Intel processor add the following lines :

```
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "MacBookPro14,3"
board-id = "Mac-551B86E5744E2388"
smc.version = "0"
serialNumber = "C02ZJS7SMD6M"
```

For AMD add this :

```
smc.version = "0"
cpuid.0.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1011"
cpuid.0.ebx = "0111:0101:0110:1110:0110:0101:0100:0111"
cpuid.0.ecx = "0110:1100:0110:0101:0111:0100:0110:1110"
cpuid.0.edx = "0100:1001:0110:0101:0110:1110:0110:1001"
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:0111:0001"
cpuid.1.ebx = "0000:0010:0000:0001:0000:1000:0000:0000"
cpuid.1.ecx = "1000:0010:1001:1000:0010:0010:0000:0011"
cpuid.1.edx = "0000:0111:1000:1011:1111:1011:1111:1111"
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
hw.model = "MacBookPro14,3"
board-id = "Mac-551B86E5744E2388"
```

You may now launch the VM in VMware and it should start installing macOS.

Source :
[Installer macOS Monterey sur PC avec VMware](https://www.tech2tech.fr/installer-macos-monterey-sur-pc-avec-vmware/) (French)

Comment: Incompatibility is irrelevant. It is against the EULA, & no matter what you may think of that, some of us equate it with asking for keygens for Windows. Win: if you want the [paid] OS, buy it. Mac: if you want the [free] OS, buy the hardware it's licensed  on.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Your link is not categorical about this point, some answers saying that a macOS VM is a gray area. I had years ago a macOS VM which I used once only to check one answer that I gave here for macOS. How did this damage Apple in any way? In actual fact, I can testify that it's impossible to use a macOS VM to do any real work, because the performance is atrocious and some things simply don't work. As you said, for macOS one needs the real hardware. I think Apple knows it, which is why it's not worried about Hackintosh.

Comment: It's categorical about it being off-topic, which is why we shouldn't answer questions on the topic. It doesn't have to be categorical about the legality. BTW, I have several macOS VMs here all of which run just fine… on a Mac. This later revisit also points out it's against SE's ToS too. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12050/revisit-the-hackintosh-policy